# Implementation of logic function using a multiplexer

Tags: boolean-algebra, combinatory-logic

A question asks me to simplify the following boolean expression then use a multiplexer to implement it.

$$\overline{A}BC + \overline{A+B+C}+A\overline{B}\overline{C} + B\overline{C}$$

I evaluated the expression and got this result:

$$\overline{A}BC + \overline{C}$$

However, I stuck here because I cannot see the connection between this expression and the multiplexer. Can someone give some hint? Much appreciated :)

Comment: Why, in the simplification, have you dropped $B$? I see it in the very contexts $C$ appears. Why have you dropped $A$, why $BC$? (You can use variables/signals on the "select inputs" of a multiplexer to select from any expressions of your choice, including *undefined*, $0$, and $1$.)

Comment: @greybeard I know what a multiplexer is. For my simplification process, since
$$\overline{A+B+C} = \overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\cdot\overline{C}$$

Comment: @greybeard Could you please tell me which part I did wrong:
$$\overline{A}BC +\overline{A}\cdot\overline{B}\cdot\overline{C}+A\overline{B}\overline{C}+B\overline{C}$$
$$\overline{A}BC +\overline{B}\overline{C}(\overline{A}+A)+B\overline{C}$$
$$\overline{A}BC+\overline{B}\overline{C}+B\overline{C}$$
$$\overline{A}BC + \overline{C}$$

Comment: (This is not chat.) Firefox 76.0.1 didn't render the equations the more convincing way Opera 30.0 does - give me a moment.

Comment: (In particular, Firefox didn't show *any* overstrikes.)

Comment: I now think your simplification is correct, if not minimal. I don't quite see the point of first simplifying just to go on and *use a multiplexer to implement it* - do that, implement the original and compare.

Comment: @greybeard However, if you use Karnaugh map to simplify this, you will get a slightly different answer:

$$\overline{A}B + \overline{C}$$
which confuses me.
Do you know why they produce different answers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108384/discussion-between-greybeard-and-feanor-tang).